# Sort content of field alphabetically in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Please be advised that I don't want to order the results. I would like to order the content of specific field.

Explanation:

I extract some values in a field - lets call it field1 - inside this field1 i can have something like this:

AAA BBB
AAA
BBB
CCC
AAA CCC BBB
BBB AAA
BBB AAA CCC

what I would like to do is to sort the value of the fields before I count them since AAA BBB and BBB AAA are the same

so final output of count would be this:

```
| stats count by field1
AAA BBB     3
AAA         1
BBB         2
CCC         1
AAA CCC BBB 2
```

I tried to order, sort, split, replace,
very important, I don't want to use static lookup tables, eval case, match because the values are created dynamically

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following will meet your needs:

```
| eval sorted= mvjoin(mvsort(split(field1, " ")), " ")
```

We create multi-value field, sort it, and then join it back to a string.

my test:

````
| makeresults 
| eval field1="AAA BBB,AAA,BBB,CCC,AAA CCC BBB,BBB AAA,BBB AAA CCC"
| makemv field1 delim=","
| mvexpand field1
``` The above is just data ```
|  eval sorted= mvjoin(mvsort(split(field1, " ")), " ")
| stats count by sorted
````

Comment: Thanks. I will test this and let you know. However I've noticed that you are creating this field with all those values. My log has one of those values in each event. So one raw has "AAA BBB" and next raw has "CCC" for example

Comment: Run just the "upper" part and you will see my data set.

Comment: you are a wizard :) works thank you very much